# why c reacts to 0 in begining of int

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, int

when I Input:

```
char J[10] = "0";
int num = 111011;
NumToString(J, num);
```

To the function:

```
int NumToString(char (*J)[], int num){
    int i=0;
    int j;
    char k[10];
    for(;i<=9;i++){
        (*J)[i]= ((num%10)+'0');
        num/=10;
    }
    if(num==0){
        J=(&k);
        return suc; // a macro; suc = 1
    }
    else{
        return fail; // a macro fail=0;
    }

}
```

It converts to Int to String perfectly but when the int is defined as:

```
int num = 0111011;
```

The output is 37385 from the function.

Comment: "It converts to Int to String perfectly" --> not quite.  `J[]`, as a _string_, lacks a _null character_ after `NumToString(J, num);`.

Comment: *"warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char [10]' to parameter of type 'char (*)[]'"*

Comment: And the line `J=(&k)` is taking the address of a local variable. That local variable ceases to exist when the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

This is because starting a numerical value with zero indicates that the number is a octal-constant.

```
int d = 42; // decimal
int o = 052; // octal
int x = 0x2a; // hex
int X = 0X2A; // hex
```

See the following link:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant